# Unable to recvfrom UDP client, bytes object has no attribute recvfrom

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am a newbie to socket programming and I want to send two numbers from client side to server side in UDP and the server will return the product of the two numbers.

When I send the numbers from the client side, there is an error on the server side that "bytes object has no attribute recvfrom".

This is my code

**Client side**

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

c = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

c.connect(('localhost', 11111))

num1 = input('Input a number: ')
num2 = input('Enter a second number: ')

c.sendto(num1.encode('utf-8'), ('localhost', 11111))
c.sendto(num2.encode('utf-8'), ('localhost', 11111))

print(c.recvfrom(1024).decode())
```

**Server side**

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
print('Socket created!')

s.bind(('localhost', 11111))

while True:
    c, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)

    num1 = c.recvfrom(1024)
    num2 = c.recvfrom(1024)

    print('Received from client having address:', addr)
    print('The product of the numbers sent by the client is:', num1*num2)

    s.sendto(bytes('***Welcome To The Server***', 'utf-8'))
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'bytes' object has no attribute 'recvfrom'
  File "C:\Users\kryptex\Downloads\Compressed\attachments\udpserv1.py", line 11, in <module>
    num1 = c.recvfrom(1024)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)

num1 = c.recvfrom(1024)
num2 = c.recvfrom(1024)
```

`c` are the bytes returned by the `s.recvfrom`. You likely meant `s.recvfrom` instead of `c.recvfrom`. Hint: give your variables more clear and longer names which describe their actual function.

Apart from that it is unclear to me what the intend of `c, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)` actually is, since there is no matching send on the client side. I have the feeling that you are confusing TCP and UDP sockets and tried to implement some kind of TCP `accept` here, matching the `c.connect` on the client side. This is wrong though.

Comment: c means the client-side socket and s is the server-side socket. And isn't c.sendto the matching send on the client side?
The c, addr = s.recvfrom(1024) is equivalent to data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024).

Comment: @Kryptex: Looks like I guessed right that you are trying to apply TCP concepts to UDP - where they don't belong. There is no server-side and client-side socket in UDP. There is no accept a connection or similar. I recommend to study the documentation what recvfrom actually returns - the received data and where they were received from and not some kind of client-side socket